# Adjusting Height,Width of JavaFX ScatterChart

Tags: charts, javafx

I have initialised my chart with a particular height.
On a button click I want to resize the chart by a factor of 2 and position it at a particular X,Y.
Unable to do so.

I have done the following there is no response. I debugged and the saw that the prefWidth is changing but visually no change.

```
graphScatterChartOne.setPrefWidth(graphScatterChartOne.getWidth()/2);
graphScatterChartOne.setLayoutX(0);
graphScatterChartTwo.setLayoutX(graphScatterChartOne.getWidth());
```

Comment: Layout is normally under controll of the parent container, e.g. Pane or H/VBox etc... so it would be good to know the context weher your chart is layouted into....

Comment: I figured that my ScatterChart was in a AnchorPane and the left, right, top and bottom anchors were all set. Hence, the ScatterCharts were streched.